# How do I add .htm files to root of my SP2010 site

Tags: 2010, html, pages

I'm currently working on moving our current website from Dreamweaver to SharePoint, and I have a requirement to have an .htm file at the root of my SP2010 site. The reason is that we have software that expects a specific URL, which looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/productupdates.htm?version=xxxx&blah=xxxx&whatever=xxxx
```

I tried adding the .htm file to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80` folder, but going to that .htm page gives me a 404 error.

What options do I have here, assuming that changing our software is NOT an option?

Is there any configuration within IIS I can do to allow this .htm file to work? Or perhaps within SharePoint 2010 itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file isn't expecting to be in a document library, you can use SharePoint Designer to upload the file to the root of the web site, and also set this page to be the HomePage for the site within SharePoint Designer.

SharePoint Designer is a free product available from Microsoft, here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16573

Comment: ^^ SharePoint Designer is the easiest way to upload an HTML document to the root of your site application.

Comment: It's elegant in its simplicity! Uploading the page via Designer did the trick, and adding querystring parameters to the URL of this page, and executing JavaScript within this .htm file are still possible. Perfect!

Thank you, James.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to provision html at the root of the site by a FEATURE that uses Module element.

From VS.NET add project item of type Module, replace sample.txt with your html file and make sure the elements.xml looks like below assuming you have sample.htm file abd your module name is RootModule. The name of module and html file can be different in your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="RootModule">
  <File Path="RootModule\Sample.html" Url="Sample.html" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but James had a much easier solution to the exact problem I was facing. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a 2010 Enterprise, you can enable the publishing infrastructure and features.  This will give you a link in Site Settings called Welcome Page.  This will allow you to set a different home page.  So you can upload your htm page to a document library and then set that as the new home page.

Comment: Thank you too, Eric, for the idea, though this one was certainly more than I think I needed.

Comment: No worries, while mine is a valid option, it isn't the answer in this case.  As always with SharePoint, there's more than one way to skin a cat.